# ¿Cómo saber que datos están duplicados en Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics

Tengo unas dudas sobre GA. Si tengo el código duplicado tanto en el código fuente como en tag manager y he visto que se envían dos hits repetidos uno de cada uno, ¿esto a que métricas me afecta? Sobre todo tengo dudas si en las métricas que veo en la sección de audiencia como "numero de visitas por pagina", "usuarios"... y si no afecta a estas métricas ¿a cuales serian?

Gracias!

Comment: Si tienes datos duplicados afectaría a tus estadísticas ya que estas no serían del todo reales, es algo que debes evitar. Recuerda que si buscas opiniones debes revisar [ask]., saludos.

Comment: Hola, ya he cambiado la forma de hacer la pregunta según el enlace que me has enviado. Muchas gracias. Por otro lado, quiere decir que el numero de visitas por pagina y usuarios estaría duplicado? ¿Como podria saberlo?

Answer (score 0):

La información no se duplica, simplemente que a la vez se lanzan dos etiqueatas se reemplaza por el propio servidor de GA, ya que por milisegundos no es posible tener el mismo evento duplicado.

Además, ten en cuenta que si hay dos etiquetas con dos nombres de scripts diferentes a dos propiedades de GA diferentes, sí se envian dos eventos (los mismos), por ser dos entidades diferentes.